# Can this be done with one MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables and want to return all employees that are active from the *emp* table and any time they have worked from the *timeclock* table.  The query below works great if all of the active employees have time logged between two dates but if the employee doesn't have any time logged between the dates they are not returned. I need all employees that are active returned whether they have time or not between dates.

```
 emp table
 user      active
 jblow          1 
 jdoe           1
 dcook          0
 ajones         1

 timeclock table
 user      date         hours
 jblow     2014-06-01     8.3
 dcook     2013-12-23     7.5
 jdoe      2014-06-03     8.1
 jblow     2014-06-02     7.9
 jblow     2014-05-23     8.0

 SELECT emp.user, emp.active, timeclock.date, timeclock.hours FROM emp JOIN timeclock ON emp.user = timeclock.user AND emp.active = 1 AND timeclock.date BETWEEN "20140601" AND "20140603" ORDER BY emp.user ASC
```

The query above doesn't return ajones because he doesn't have any time logged between the dates but I need it to return all active employees.  The results I looking for would be something like this:

```
 ajones  1  null          null
 jblow   1  2014-06-01     8.3
 jblow   1  2014-06-02     7.9
 jdoe    1  2014-06-03     8.1
```

Comment: Why is it important to do it in one query? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Returning left table values regardless of matching right table values is precisely what [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) is for.

Besides adding "LEFT" before "JOIN", you'll want to move your `emp.active = 1` condition from the JOIN conditions to the WHERE conditions, because you want that to apply after the join attempt whether or not there is a matching *timeclock* record.

```
SELECT emp.user, emp.active, timeclock.date, timeclock.hours
FROM emp
LEFT JOIN timeclock
  ON emp.user = timeclock.user
  AND timeclock.date BETWEEN "20140601" AND "20140603"
WHERE emp.active = 1
ORDER BY emp.user ASC
```

<sup>[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91958/4)</sup>

Results:

```
|   USER | ACTIVE |                        DATE |  HOURS |
|--------|--------|-----------------------------|--------|
| ajones |      1 |                      (null) | (null) |
|  jblow |      1 | June, 02 2014 00:00:00+0000 |    7.9 |
|  jblow |      1 | June, 01 2014 00:00:00+0000 |    8.3 |
|   jdoe |      1 | June, 03 2014 00:00:00+0000 |    8.1 |
```